# Taking Parameters and Returning Results with tuples and integers

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'm trying to return the sum of all the values in one of my parameters (nums_tuple) that are greater or equal to the min_value, as per below:

```
def add_numbers(nums_tuple, min_value):
    for n in nums_tuple:
        if nums_tuple[n] += min_value:
            return
total = add_numbers((21, 4, 7, 19, 1), 15)
print(total)
```

Result should be 40 as 21 + 19, since they are the integers inside my tuple that are greater than the value of my other parameter (min_value)
I am going wrong somewhere and can't see where...could anyone offer some advice please? Thanks

Comment: This wont work .if nums_tuple[n] += min_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+=` operator adds a value to an existing variable. You need to use the `>=` operator to check if a value exceeds or is equal to a certain value. There are a couple of other issues with your code, e.g. not returning a value. This is more pythonic:

`sum(x for x in nums_tuple if x >= min_value)`

Answer (score 1):

To be close to your code, try the following:

```py
def add_numbers(nums_tuple, min_value):
    total = 0
    for n in range(len(nums_tuple)):
        if nums_tuple[n] >= min_value:
            total += nums_tuple[n]
    return total

total = add_numbers((21, 4, 7, 19, 1), 15)
print(total)
```

In your original code, you are putting `nums_tuple[n] += min_value`, which means "add `min_value` to `nums_tuple[n]`" (i.e., a statement). This is not what `if` is expecting (at least in python): you need to put some expression that is true or false, such as `True` or `nums_tuple[n] >= min_value`.

By the way you don't really need to do the complicated `for` loop.

```py
def add_numbers(nums_tuple, min_value):
    return sum([n for n in nums_tuple if n >= min_value])
```

would suffice.

Comment: Your answer is the most well-written answer on Stack Overflow, I'm so proud of you! There are some things that can be improved, such as replacing `for n in range(len(nums_tuple))` with `for n in nums_tuple` and removing the brackets on the list comprehension used in `sum`, but these things don't even touch the fucking perfection of your answer.

Comment: that was magical, you saved my night! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @enzo Thanks! The first point was also in my mind, but I thought the OP wanted to use `n` as the index, so I left it as is. As for the second point, I totally agree with you! Although I am aware of it, I often forget to remove the brackets.

Comment: I agree - crystal clear answer and so bloody well explained!

Comment: @Jose Glad it helped!

Comment: it really did :) list comprehension is something I have started today and now it is much clearer thanks to your explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments. `if nums_tuple[n] += min_value` wont work. Instead I think you want to check if the number is greater than `>`.

```
def add_numbers(nums_tuple, min_value):
    return sum([num for num in nums_tuple if num > min_value])
total = add_numbers((21, 4, 7, 19, 1), 15)
```

This problem can be solved using list comprehension.

```
40
```

Additionally I would like to point out that this is totally unessaccary. You are iterating through the list already, no need to access elements in the list. That won't work if the elements in `nums_tuple` are all greater than `len(nums_tuple)`. You will get indexError

```
for n in nums_tuple:
    nums_tuple[n]
```

Comment: I messed up a bit in there, I am with you! Thank you for the help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you still lack understanding of Python Programming Langauge so will just explain few key errors in your code:

1- when you say `for n in num_tuple` that means you are taking each element in the tuple, not the index (if you want the index you would do `for i in range(len(num_tuple))`)

2- your if statement should be a condition, not an assignment when you say `nums_tuple[n] += min_value` this will just update the value and it will not work as discussed in the first point that you are looping through elements, not indexes so you need something like `if n > min_value`

3- your return should be at the end after you are done summing all the numbers that are greater than the minimum value

**Working code**

```
def add_numbers(nums_tuple, min_value):
    result = 0
    for n in nums_tuple:
        if n > min_value:
            result += n
    return result
total = add_numbers((21, 4, 7, 19, 1), 15)
print(total)
```

Comment: I couldnt agree more with you - still early days for me getting to know Python. thank you for the explanations, muchly appreciated :)

Comment: anytime Jose! I recommend learning Python from Udemy Python from Zero to Hero it is an amazing course for beginners and I took it myself in my early stages

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_numbers(nums_tuple, min_value):
    values = filter(lambda x: x > min_value, nums_tuple)
    return sum(values)
```

Filter functions can also be a good alternative in this case since they only pass values from the sequence provided that meet the condition provided as True. The second argument is the sequence you want to iterate over. However, since filter functions return filter objects you need to use list() function to unpack the values if you want to explicitly see the values that met your condition.